# Determine whether caller is called from EXE or DLL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I need to determine the caller code whether is coming from EXE or DLL.

### DLL

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
    __declspec(dllexport) void say_hello();
    __declspec(dllexport) void getCurrentModuleName();
#else
    __declspec(dllimport) void say_hello();
    __declspec(dllexport) void getCurrentModuleName();
#endif

#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Dbghelp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "dll.h"
#include "Psapi.h"

__declspec(naked) void *GetStackPointer()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, esp
        ret
    }
}

void getCurrentModuleName()
{
    BOOL result = SymInitialize(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL , TRUE);
    DWORD64 dwBaseAddress = SymGetModuleBase64(GetCurrentProcess(), (DWORD64)GetStackPointer());
    TCHAR szBuffer[50];
    GetModuleBaseName(GetCurrentProcess(), (HMODULE) dwBaseAddress, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer));
    std::wcout << _T("--->") << szBuffer << std::endl;
}

void say_hello() {
    getCurrentModuleName();
}
```

### EXE

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include "dll.h"

int main() {
    printf ("ENTERING EXE CODE...\n");

    getCurrentModuleName();

    printf ("ENTERING DLL CODE...\n");

    say_hello();

    getchar();
}
```

Here is the output.

```
ENTERING EXE CODE...
--->exe.exe
ENTERING DLL CODE...
--->exe.exe
```

I wish I can get

```
ENTERING EXE CODE...
--->exe.exe
ENTERING DLL CODE...
--->dll.dll
```

As the last caller code are from DLL itself (say_hello in DLL)

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. The limitation is that, it is only able to trace up to 62 frames.

```
// Must have in order for us to turned address into module name.
SymInitialize(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL , TRUE);
// Limitation of RtlCaptureStackBackTrace.
const int kMaxCallers = 62; 
void* callers[kMaxCallers];
int count = RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, kMaxCallers, callers, NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    TCHAR szBuffer[50];
    DWORD64 dwBaseAddress = SymGetModuleBase64(GetCurrentProcess(), (DWORD64)callers[i]);
    GetModuleBaseName(GetCurrentProcess(), (HMODULE) dwBaseAddress, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer));
    std::wcout << _T("--->") << szBuffer << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

GetStackAddress is returning the value of ESP, which is a reference to the stack. The stack is allocated per thread, independently of any modules loaded in the process.
What you need to do is extract from the stack, the value of the return address - which will be an address in the calling module.

Given that the usual prefix code in a function is:

```
push ebp
mov  ebp,esp
sub  esp, bytes_of_local_variables
```

esp is going to be somewhat random, but [ebp] should be pointing at the previous ebp, and [ebp+4] should be pointing at the current frames return address.

So, you could try this:

```
__declspec(naked) void *GetReturnAddressAssumingStandardFramePointers()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, [ebp+4]
        ret
    }
}
```

Just make sure that functions that call that arn't compiled with [/Oy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxx5t2c%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: But naked doesn't insert any prolog or epilog code. I'm pretty sure you want `mov eax, [esp]` instead. (I.e. FPO is irrelevant for naked functions).

Comment: We use naked to ensure that GetReturnAddress... DOESN't insert any prologue code: The prolog code we are interested in is for GetCurrentModuleName: We want to find out who called GetCurrentModuleName, Not who called GetRAASFP (we already know that answer: its always GetCurrentModuleName).

Comment: Since I have no control on the modules, whether they are compiled with frame pointer being omitted. Do you have a portable to walk through, without making assumption on the availability of frame pointer?

Comment: um, You wrote `getCurrentModuleName` - which is the function that calls GetRASSFFP. So it is getCurrentModuleName's stack frame the code interrogates. It doesn't matter how the other module was built at all.

Answer (score 1):

In that case use the return address of the function, which you can figure out by looking directly at the stack.  The rest of the answer still applies.

Comment: Yup.  The _ReturnAddress() instrinsic provides it without hacking.  Furthermore, VirtualQuery() gets the base address which you can cast to HMODULE.  Then GetModuleFileName() gets you the dll/exe name.

Comment: Except that the region's base address might not be the base address of the module...

Answer (score 0):

You get stack pointer inside `getCurrentModuleName()` which is in DLL, but you need to get returning address from stack at the beginning of `getCurrentModuleName()` which shows you where `getCurrentModuleName()` was called from.

Answer (score 0):

Use EnumProcessModules().  For each one call GetModuleInformation().  Compare the address of the function that you're executing (using a function pointer) to the lpBaseOfDll and SizeOfImage members of the MODULEINFO struct.  If it falls within the range, you know that's the current module.  If so, use GetModuleBaseName to retrieve the name of the module.

Comment: For this case function pointer is always in dll address space, no matter where it was called from. But the task is to figure out the module it was called from.